# React 16 in code pen

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I want to try using React in CodePen but I cannot get it set up.

my JS looks like this:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Hello, ES6 and React!</h1>
    </div>
  }
}
ReactDom.render(<Application/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

my html looks like this:

```
<div id="app"></app>
```

I import React and ReactDom as in the image below but I get an error 'ReactDom is not defined'.

Does anyone know how to set this up?

https://codepen.io/goughjo02/pen/ajGZoL

[image: javascript settings in codepen]

Comment: try `ReactDOM.render`, rather than `ReactDom.render`

Comment: thank you. silly me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo error. You should use ReactDOM instead of ReactDom.

Comment: you have a typo too :D

Comment: hahaha yeah, I'm sorry, by keyboard isn't working that well on a's. I will fix it